# Android Kotlin SharedPreferences saving error

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have a problem saving data correctly into the SharedPreferences. Somehow the last editor.putString
method is written into all of my preferences, and i don't know why.

Here is my code :

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private var firstnameEditText : EditText ? = null
private var lastnameEditText : EditText ?  = null
private var firstnameTextView : TextView ? = null
private var lastnameTextView : TextView ? = null
private var saveButton : Button? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    firstnameEditText = findViewById(R.id.main_activity_firstname_editText) as EditText
    lastnameEditText = findViewById(R.id.main_activity_lastname_editText) as EditText
    firstnameTextView = findViewById(R.id.main_activity_firstname_textView) as TextView
    lastnameTextView = findViewById(R.id.main_activity_lastname_textView) as TextView
    saveButton = findViewById(R.id.main_activity_save_button) as Button
    saveButton?.setOnClickListener { saveData() }
    loadData()
}

private fun loadData(){
    try {
        val sharedPref = getSharedPreferences( getString(R.string.sharedPrefs) , Context.MODE_PRIVATE) ?: return
        val firstname = sharedPref.getString(getString(R.string.firstname_key), "")
        val lastname = sharedPref.getString(getString(R.string.lastname_key), "")
        firstnameTextView?.text = firstname
        lastnameTextView?.text = lastname
    } catch (ex : Exception){
        Log.d("Main", ex.toString())
    }
}

private fun saveData(){
    try {
        val sharedPref = getSharedPreferences( getString(R.string.sharedPrefs) , Context.MODE_PRIVATE) ?: return
        with(sharedPref.edit()){
            putString(getString(R.string.firstname_key), firstnameEditText?.text.toString())
            putString(getString(R.string.lastname_key), lastnameEditText?.text.toString())
            apply()
        }
        loadData()
    } catch (ex : Exception){
        Log.d("Main", ex.toString())
    }
}
```

}

After I click on the save button, the result is the following :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0QT9x.png)

According to the official documentation, I'm doing everything right.
[enter link description here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences)

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post the value of `R.string.firstname_key` and `R.string.lastname_key` ?

Answer (score 0):

I gess the value of `R.string.firstname_key` and `R.string.lastname_key` are same.

Could you check those values in `strings.xml`

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this way--

```
val sharedPreference =  getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE_NAME",Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
var editor = sharedPreference.edit()
editor.putString("username","Anupam")
editor.putLong("l",100L)
editor.commit()
```

And retrieve data -->

```
sharedPreference.getString("username","defaultName")
sharedPreference.getLong("l",1L)
```

Above you initialize multiple time getSharedPreferences,  getting and saving the value with the same instance